# Unity C# Pipe Server premature CallBack?

Tags: c#, pipe, unity-game-engine

I've been using the same pipe code for other projects, but when I try to use it on Unity, I get premature ConnectionCallBack (i.e. I receive a callback when there's no connection!)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Text;

public delegate void DelegateMessage(string Reply);

public class PipeServer
{
        public event DelegateMessage PipeMessage;
        string _pipeName;

        public void Listen(string PipeName)
        {
            try
            {
                // Set to class level var so we can re-use in the async callback method
                _pipeName = PipeName;
                // Create the new async pipe 
                NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName,
                   PipeDirection.In, 5, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
                // Wait for a connection
                pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection
                (new AsyncCallback(WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer);
            }
            catch (Exception oEX)
            {
                Debug.Log(oEX.Message);
            }
        }

        //this callback gets called right after I listen to the namedpipe!
        private void WaitForConnectionCallBack(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the pipe
                NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = (NamedPipeServerStream)iar.AsyncState;
                // End waiting for the connection
                pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(iar);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
                // Read the incoming message
                pipeServer.Read(buffer, 0, 255);

                // Convert byte buffer to string
                string stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


                // Pass message back to calling form
                PipeMessage.Invoke(stringData);

                // Kill original sever and create new wait server
                pipeServer.Close();
                pipeServer = null;
                pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(_pipeName, PipeDirection.In,
                   5, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

                // Recursively wait for the connection again and again....
                pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(
                   new AsyncCallback(WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log(e.Message);
                Debug.Log(e.StackTrace);
                return;
            }
        }

}
```

this is the Error message that I'm getting:

```
e.Message = The operation completed successfully.
e.StackTrace = at System.IO.Pipes.Win32NamedPipeServer.WaitForConnection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.WaitForConnection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

why is this happening?